# convert already gotten date to new timezone javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Is it possible for me to convert

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"
```

to this?

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (New_York or whatever its actually called)"
```

I am using a component called react-datepicker

My datePicker is returning a date like this, Im in Colorado.

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"
```

When i convert this to UTC i get

```
"2022-10-27T08:00:00Z"
```

My component is ALWAYS going to return me a time in my local timezone, which is Denver. I would like to be able to select a time, have it return me the first date, then somehow convert that to the second date in New york time.

```
"Thu Oct 27 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (New_York or whatever its actually called)"
```

This way when I convert to utc I can get the output below

```
"2022-10-27T06:00:00Z"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Instatiate a new `Date` object with the offset. See [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone) for more specifics.

```
const date1 = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+07:00');
const date2 = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT-02:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how I achieved what I wanted using the moment timezone:**

```js
//date coming in like this Sat Oct 29 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)

const applyOffset = date.setTime(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60_000);
const actualTime = new Date(applyOffset).toISOString().replace("Z", "");
const toTz = momentt.tz(actualTime, timezone).format();

const getUTCTime = momentt.utc(toTz).format();
```

Note timezone variable getting passed to `momentt.tz(actualTime, timezone).format()` can be any named timezone like `America/New_York` or `America/Chicago`

As a result of the `console.log(getUTCTime)`, I get `2022-10-29T06:00:00Z` If I make timezone `America/New_York`